# Rational approximations of logarithms of ratios of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-approximation

I noticed that there are many pairs of primes $p_1, p_2$ such that $$\frac {\log(p_1/p_2)}{ \log(2)} \approx \frac{N}{69324}$$ for some natural N with an error of order $10^{-8}$ . I found around 20 pairs, but more can be found if one has the patience.

Other such sets with other common denominators can likewise be found, as can sets with $\log(3)$ or $\log(5)$ in place of $\log(2)$ in the denominator slot of the LHS.

**I would like to know whether this is some interesting property of primes, or whether it is statistically unremarkable and expected through pure chance**. It would certainly be unremarkable if each ratio had its own denominator, but here they all have $69324.$

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \text{Prime $\#$1} & \text{Prime $\#$2} & \text{Numerator, N } & \text{Denominator, D} & \text{Error= }\frac{\log \left(\frac{\text{p1}}{\text{p2}}\right)}{\log (2)}-\frac{N}{D}  \\
 461 & 3 & 503546 & 69324 & \text{-5.305e-8} \\
 617 & 3 & 532697 & 69324 & \text{-3.599e-8} \\
 1201 & 3 & 599310 & 69324 & \text{-5.359e-8} \\
 661 & 5 & 488497 & 69324 & \text{-1.893e-8} \\
 1567 & 5 & 574825 & 69324 & \text{-3.483e-8} \\
 449 & 7 & 416167 & 69324 & \text{-6.65e-8} \\
 1367 & 7 & 527517 & 69324 & \text{-1.173e-8} \\
 1453 & 7 & 533619 & 69324 & \text{-1.613e-8} \\
 149 & 11 & 260640 & 69324 & \text{1.417e-8} \\
 1901 & 11 & 515293 & 69324 & \text{9.967e-9} \\
 401 & 23 & 285885 & 69324 & \text{-1.567e-8} \\
 191 & 29 & 188523 & 69324 & \text{2.263e-8} \\
 479 & 31 & 273808 & 69324 & \text{7.581e-10} \\
 461 & 41 & 242015 & 69324 & \text{2.242e-8} \\
 1559 & 61 & 324136 & 69324 & \text{-3.233e-9} \\
 881 & 67 & 257671 & 69324 & \text{1.148e-8} \\
 449 & 71 & 184459 & 69324 & \text{-1.884e-8} \\
 887 & 73 & 249772 & 69324 & \text{-4.843e-8} \\
 317 & 79 & 138964 & 69324 & \text{-2.396e-8} \\
 1019 & 107 & 225405 & 69324 & \text{-2.148e-9} \\
 641 & 193 & 120050 & 69324 & \text{8.11e-9} \\
 787 & 197 & 138521 & 69324 & \text{-1.657e-8} \\
\end{array}
$$